# before_create rule not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

In my user.rb model I have the following:

```
    before_create :check_name

    def check_name
        user = User.where(:name => self.name, :place => self.place)
        if user.present?
          p "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
          @error = "Same combination of name and place are already present"
          return @error
        end
      end
```

and in my controller:

```
    def create
        error_flag = false
        @user =User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          error_flag = true
          @success = I18n.t('user.success.user_created')
        else
          @error = find_error(@user)
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          format.js {
            render :layout => false,
                   :locals => {
                     :request => error_flag,
                     :user => @user
                   }
          }
        end
  end
```

My aim was to not create a user if the condition defined in the model is true, however the user is created anyway. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do just a simple thing add this in your model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :place
```

and remove all the code i.e before_create and its method.

Answer (score 2):

Your `before_create` callback in model do not adds error in the model.
[Use `validate` instead of `before_create`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) for add errors, then your records do not save to database and `@user.save` returned false:

```
validate :check_name

def check_name
   user = User.where(:name => self.name, :place => self.place)
   errors.add(:base, "Something wrong") if user.present?
end
```

if you want use `before_create` callback for add errors:

```
before_create :check_name

def check_name
   user = User.where(:name => self.name, :place => self.place)
   errors.add(:base, "Something wrong") if user.present?
end
```

More prefered uses `validate` for this case instead of `before_create`. and read how validate model and add errors.

Read [`how validate model and add errors.`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Before Create is just a callback which will be executed when you call User.save. But if you want to stop creation of records. you go with validation.Write your custom validation

validates_with :check_name